# WCF consumed by Java - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, consuming

A colleague of mine is attempting to consume a web service that has been developed using WCF.

The error received is:

IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.DetermineWsImportExtensionCommand.buildServiceStructure(Unknown Source)
  at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxws.creation.command.DetermineWsImportExtensionCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Consuming the web service from Visual Studio is okay.

I appreciate this is vague and can supply more information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSDL for this service was not valid.

[How to validate your WSDL](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-validate-your-wsdl.html)